# localStorage returning null object

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a variable that needs to be stored in localStorage everytime a button is clicked. the way I am doing this is:

```
localStorage.setItem('newFileName', localStorage.getItem('newFileName') + ",<br><br>" + newFileName);
```

and then I am fetching it like this:

```
ending = localStorage.getItem('newFileName');
```

this is supposed to return the string:

newFileName, newFileName, etc.. however it is returning as:

null, newFileName, newFileName

I have no clue why? Can someone maybe help me out?

Comment: Because it isn't initialized.

Comment: ... and `null` becomes `"null"`. You need an `if` statement there.

Comment: `localStorage.newFileName` is not set to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using localStorage.getItem within the setItem call. Since the item won't have been set before this the getItem call is returning null. 
You need to check if it has been initialised before setting it.
Something like

```
if (localStorage.getItem("newFileName")) {
    localStorage.setItem('newFileName', localStorage.getItem('newFileName') + ",<br><br>" + newFileName);
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('newFileName', newFileName);
}
```